# I want to drag an element defined as a data attribute and my question is how do I address it in this code:

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to drag an element defined as a data attribute and my question is how do I address it in this code snippet:

```
event.dataTransfer.setData ("dice", event.target.             );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)
- (Use preferably [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget))

```html
<div data-dice="hello!" draggable="true">
```

```js
event.currentTarget.dataset.dice    // "hello!"
```

Example:

```js
const EL_dropZone = document.querySelector("#dropZone");
const ELS_dice = document.querySelectorAll("[data-dice]");

EL_dropZone.addEventListener("drop", dropHandler);
EL_dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", dragoverHandler)
ELS_dice.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("dragstart", dragstartHandler));

function dragstartHandler(evt) {
  evt.dataTransfer.setData("application/my-dice", evt.currentTarget.dataset.dice);
}

function dragoverHandler(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
}

function dropHandler(evt) {
  const data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("application/my-dice");
  evt.currentTarget.textContent += data + " ";
}
```

```css
#dropZone {
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 1em;
  border: 1px dashed #0bf;
}

[data-dice] {
  display: inline-block;
  background: gold;
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<div data-dice="Hello" draggable="true">DICE 1</div>
<div data-dice="World!" draggable="true">DICE 2</div>

<div id="dropZone"></div>
```